# Sklearn, CART , стандартных параметров, библиотеки Pandas, файла data.csv

Tags: python, scikit-learn

С помощью библиотеки Sklearn на основе алгоритма CART производится построение дерева классификации с использованием стандартных параметров. Для этого с использованием библиотеки Pandas осуществляется загрузка обучающей выборки данных из файла data.csv, который содержит значения атрибутов ("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6") и метки классов ("C"). Требуется определить коэффициенты значимости каждого атрибута (с использованием feature_importances_) и в качестве ответа записать максимальное значение коэффициента. Ответ требуется округлить с помощью функции round() до 3 знаков и записать через символ ".".

Comment: Задание - вижу. Вопроса - не вижу. Делайте ваше задание, в чём вопрос то?

Comment: Представьте, пожалуйста, свой код. Похоже просто копирование некоего домашнего задания.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

# Загрузка данных из файла data.csv
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# Разделение данных на атрибуты (X) и метки классов (y)
X = data.drop('C', axis=1)
y = data['C']

# Создание и обучение модели дерева классификации
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)

# Получение коэффициентов значимости атрибутов
feature_importances = model.feature_importances_

# Нахождение максимального коэффициента значимости
max_importance = max(feature_importances)

# Округление значения до 3 знаков после запятой
max_importance_rounded = round(max_importance, 3)

# Вывод максимального значения коэффициента
print(max_importance_rounded)
```

После загрузки данных, модель дерева классификации обучается, и затем вычисляются коэффициенты значимости атрибутов с использованием feature_importances_. Максимальное значение коэффициента округляется до трех знаков после запятой и выводится на экран.

Comment: Всё это хорошо, но тут не принято за других домашнее задание делать. Человек так ничему не научится )

Comment: @CrazyElf Это что, школа? Я думал форум помощи , нет?

Comment: Помощи в чём? В том, чтобы ничему не научиться? Одно дело когда человек разбирается сам, пытается решить, застревает и ему помогают решить какие-то сложности, чтобы двигаться дальше. И другое дело, когда человек вроде как должен был что-то выучить, а вместо этого он отдал задание кому-то, кто за него это задание решил. В итоге человек ничему не научился. Вы всё ещё считаете, что это помощь? )  Это не так чтобы запрещено совсем, но не приветствуется. Пользы сообществу, да и самому автору в этом мало.

Comment: Я еще раз спрашиваю, этот ресурс что школа? Или образовательная площадка может? В вашем ответе одно да потому, "научиться", "должен был выучить", "в итоге ничему не научился" и так далее. Мне вообще по какая разница что он там должен был выучить, я дал ответ на вопрос, чему он там учится или не научится мне это неважно.

Comment: И Stack всегда был платформой "без лишней воды" как на других форумах. Есть вопрос - есть ответ, всё. Кто не хочет отвечать, не отвечает. А базары устраивать можно на других форумах